# Fire UIActionSheet in ViewDidLoad first load only

Tags: uiactionsheet, viewdidload

I have a UIActionSheet (sheet A for short) with a switch statement of which one case: fires a 2nd view. Then in the 2nd Views Viewdidload method I fire a 2nd UIActionSheet (sheet B for short). Sheet B uses a switch statement to set the text in 4 places 2xlabels & 2xtextViews.
Now because I have sheet B fired in the viewdidload method each time i select one of sheet B case's from its switch statement it reloads the view to populate the labels and textviews but relaunches the UIActionSheet again, obviously as it is in the viewdidload.

Any suggestions on how to fire sheet b on first load only?
im thinking to use an if statement. 
example

```
if (textView.text=@""){
//fire Action Sheet
}
```

any better suggestions or ideas, i read about creating a file in the viewdidload and then if file exists it would not call action sheet and if file did not exist it would?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ened up changing my methods to fire from an IBAction instead of the viewDidLoad method